# Wordpress category template page doubling the posts

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a category-3.php template file which shows the category with ID3, and in it I have a loop starting like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>

<?php           
$myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=3');

$number = 0;

if($myposts):
foreach($myposts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post); 
  $number++; // for making every iteration unique
?>
```

What happens is that wordpress shows posts doubled, I think it might be because the $myposts and foreach loop. 
How can I keep the foreach loop (because I need to have a unique ID number by $number), but to retrieve the posts only once?

Thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed doubled the posts using two loop structures: both the `while` and the `foreach`. Thing is: when WP calls your `category-3.php` page, the WP_Query is already populated with posts from category ID 3. Therefore, you *do not need* to perform a new query to fetch those posts.

So you could use one of each solutions **separately**, but not together:

### 1) Using the `while` (recommended)

```
<?php 
$number = 0;
global $post;
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; 
  setup_postdata($post); 
  $number++;
endwhile;
?>
```

### or 2) Using your `foreach`

```
<?php           
$myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=3');
$number = 0;

if($myposts):
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
       setup_postdata($post); 
       $number++;
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Solution 1 works! I didn't know where to place the number iterator at start, and the global $post was also new to me. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the posts twice, if that is not what you want delete one of these loops.

This shows all posts with the category ID 3

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>
```

And this shows all posts with the category ID 3

```
<?php           
$myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=3');

$number = 0;

if($myposts):
foreach($myposts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post); 
  $number++; // for making every iteration unique
?>
```